# PHP increase session duration

Tags: php, session

I have increased the session timing to following

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//error_reporting(0);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
session_set_cookie_params(86400);

session_start();
```

But I get logged out every 1 or 2 hours randomly or if there is no activity in session.

Why does this happen?

Comment: did you try also ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);`

```
 <?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
  session_set_cookie_params(86400);

  session_start();
```